# Injector is returning null using injector.get()

Tags: angular

1. I'm facing an issue with the `injector.get(ViewContainerRef)` to get
   the instance of `ViewContainerRef`. It is returning null/undefined
   when try to get the instance of `ViewContainerRef`.
2. It is available before i reach to the class to get the instance of    `ViewContainerRef`.
   The injector argument is being passed from child to parent using constructor arguments and trying to
   get the instance using `injector.get()`.
   That is returning null all the time.
3. Please help me to come out of this situation,Thanks.

```js
export abstract class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    constructor(injector: Injector) {
        super(injector);
    }
}
```

```js
export abstract class ParentClass{
    public viewContainerRef:ViewContainerRef;
    constructor(injector: Injector) {
        this.viewContainerRef = injector.get(ViewContainerRef) **Here it is returning null.**
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz showing your issue, with a minimal reproducible example? Because the code you posted is not complete. A standard class/service cannot have a `ViewContainerRef`. I suppose you are trying to use it with components?

Comment: Yes, i'm using it in components.Implementation is similar. Component is extending a class, which is again extending a parent class.I'm trying to access ViewContainerRef inside parent class constructor,which is returning null.

Comment: That's why I'm asking for a stackblitz example. Because if I try your code, it works [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4o6bad?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, will try to reproduce the problem in stackblitz and share here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd struggled the same issue, finally identified that
injector.get(ViewContainerRef) returns null when Ivy is disabled.
(If Ivy is enabled, then injector correctly resolves it).

Seems ViewContainerRef should be specified as a param of the constructor in ViewEngine environment.